# C++ custom signal/slots destructor problem

Tags: c++, c++11

Im working on signal/slots module in my embedded project (no std lib). It works fine but Ive noticed that I need to release slot when its object is destroyed. I have slot list in "memberSlots" named variable. Slot is a pair of object and a pointer to its member function. Slot executes member function by "call" method.
The problem is that when slots "target" object is destroyed its not going to be removed from memberSlots list in signal aka it will try to execute member function from destroyed object pointer when emit on signal is called.

signal.h:

```
#include "slot.h"
#include "list.h"

template<typename Arg, typename RetType = void>
class Signal
{
    List<SlotInterface<Arg>*> memberSlots;
    List<RetType(*)(Arg)> nonMemberSlots;
public:
    ~Signal() {
        for (auto slot : memberSlots) delete slot;
    }
    template<typename Type>
    void attach(Type* object, RetType(Type::* m)(Arg)) {
        nonMemberSlots.pushBack(m);
    }
    void attach(RetType(*m)(Arg)) {
        memberSlots.pushBack(new Slot<Type, Arg, RetType>(object, m));
    }
    void emit(const Arg& arg) {
        for (auto slot : memberSlots) slot->call(arg);
        for (auto slot : nonMemberSlots) slot(arg);
    }
};
```

slot.h:

```
template <typename T>
class SlotInterface {
public:
    virtual ~SlotInterface(){}
    virtual void call(T value) = 0;
};

template <typename Target, typename ArgType, typename RetType=void>
class Slot : public SlotInterface<ArgType>
{
    Target* object;
    RetType (Target::*method)(ArgType);
public:
    Slot(Target* object, RetType (Target::*m)(ArgType)) : object(object), method(m) {}
    void call(ArgType value) override {
        (object->*method)(value);
    }
};
```

Is there any reliable solution to make it remove slot when target class is being destroyed or anything similar? I dont want to deattach slot manually since I would own a pointer then and Im trying to avoid this kind of situation.

Comment: You would need something like a weak reference. In the standard lib we have: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr.

Comment: So I need to store weak_ptr by make_shared? Seems legit, but need to implement them both because I cant find any ready to use implementation on platform im using...

Comment: If you handle your allocation / deallocation on your own you could implement an "OnBeforeFree" Event / Signal which could be used to clean up your slots / events.
Why do you not use the standard library?

Comment: Not available on platform Im using, custom ports lacks a lot of functionality and unfortunately - are mostly unreliable. 
I handle alloc/dealloc for most of the time on my own, but there are exceptions. Weak reference seems like a solution, but I think it might take a lot of time to implement it on my own.

Comment: Can you use some sort of central dispatch registry, and call the registry to say, "I'm being destroyed"? He can do the right thing everywhere.

Comment: But how do I inform central dispatch registry that object is being destroyed? AFAIK I would need to derive from class that I want to invoke member function by signal, but that solves the problem even without central dispatch registry. I would store list of signals in derived class and then in derived destructor I would remove slots from the list. I am trying to avoid deriving since it will force me to inherit from some interface on every class I want to use as slot target. 
Or maybe I misunderstood you?